# how to use list of macro definitions in one statement

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

```
 #define Member name
 template<typename Object, typename... Mem>
 struct Reflect
 {
 tuple<Mem...> membertype;

 constexpr bool validate() {
    if constexpr ((std::is_same_v<Mem, decltype(declval<Object>().Member)> 
 () && ...)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  };
```

In the code above I want to be able to use list of macros like

```
  MEMBERS(member1, member2, member3)
```

and the be able to call an expression like this

```
std::is_same_v<Mem, decltype(declval<Object>().MEMBERS>
```

Comment: you are missing a `)>` i think

Comment: Using a macro has the same effect as if you would replace each occurence of `Member` with `name` in your code. What would you gain from that?

Comment: That code is just a test I want a macro that receive a list of member names " MEMEBERS " and then test each of their types in the is_same

Comment: yes I know this is just a condensed example, but still my question holds: What do you expect to gain from using a macro?

Comment: From what I know macro is what I can use to define stuff that can be used in a member access operator like #define macro member  Object.macro;

Comment: Are you looking for something like [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)?

Comment: Oh that can work but still needs that I hardcode the members myself like #define LIST_OF_VARIABLES \
    X(value1) \
    X(value2) \
    X(value3)   i want MEMBERS(x, y, z)

Comment: I don't think you want a macro here at all. You want a second pack of pointer-to-members (`auto... Members`), and to evaluate `std::is_same_v<Mem, decltype(declval<Object>().*Members())> && ...`

Comment: Side note: `std::is_same_v<...>` is defined as `std::is_same<...>::value` which is a boolean - you cannot *call* booleans (the original `std::is_same` has an `operator()`).

Comment: Assume we are talking about two different classes C1, C2, both having a member of type int, once called n, the next time m. You now want to be able to produce `std::is_same_v<int, decltype(C1::n)>` and `std::is_same_v<int, decltype(C2::m)>` respectively? Are you aware that it is simply *impossible* (in C++) to cover both classes with one single template (i. e. you'll be forced to specialise for different classes if members differ)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this construct? Sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: How about `template <auto... Members>`, pass in pointers-to-members and deduce the type within the template?